# How can I reuse UITableViewCell only when needed?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a tableview that has a UISegmentedControl as the tableHeaderView for my tableViewController. I have two arrays as properties that will populate the cells based on which index is selected in the segmentedController. When the two arrays have a different number of items in them, I get an out of bounds exception, which I would expect. When the number of items is the same in each array, I can reload the tableView data and everything works fine. How can I prevent the controller from trying to reuse a cell when the cell isn't needed anymore?

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
            UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Downloads Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

            // 1st option selected
            if (self.downloadTypeSelector.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {

                    if (indexPath.row < self.talkDownloads.count) {

                            // Configure the cell...
                            Talk *talk = [self.talkDownloads objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

                            cell.textLabel.text = talk.title;
                            cell.detailTextLabel.text = talk.speaker;
                    }

                    // 2nd option selected
            } else if (self.downloadTypeSelector.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) {

                    if (indexPath.row < self.speechesDownloads.count) {

                            Speech *speech = [self.speechesDownloads objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

                            cell.textLabel.text = speech.title;
                            cell.detailTextLabel.text = speech.speaker;
                    } 
            }

            return cell;
    }
```

Comment: If a cell wasn't needed it wouldn't be reused.

Comment: Then why are my old cells still there when I change the segmented control's index from the default, which is 0? If I have two items in one of the arrays (A) and one in the other (B), there are still be two rows when I select the B array. I should say that the segmented control is tied to an IBAction that reloads the tableview data.

Comment: Probably you failed to do `reloadData`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you have a condition that checks downloadTypeSelector.selectedSegmentIndex and uses the respective array accordingly, which is fine.

Do you have the same if else condition in `- tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` that checks the selectedSegmentIndex and returns the correct count of the respective array?

If that works then I think checking if indexPath.row < array.count will be obsolete too.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks, that was it! I've been at it too long today